# Denying access to wp-config.php in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, file-permissions

The WordPress article [Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#securing-wp-config-php) suggests that the following can be used in `.htaccess` to deny access to anyone surfing for wp-config.php:

```
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

**My question:** considering my file permissions for wp-config.php are set at `0600`, why is adding this code necessary?

Comment: Extra layer of security?

Comment: Perhaps, but if the 0600 permission setting stays in place, is that adequate enough to deny access?

Comment: It says that the code above will deny everyone access, and 0600 would allow owner to change it. Maybe that's the difference. I'm just guessing, I haven't seen that code before.

Comment: Yep 0600 allows the owner to read and write, and everyone else can do nothing. I think the code which goes inside .htaccess is specific to accessing the file via a web browser (I may be wrong)